# How can I add a new dataset to Apache Fuseki using the command line?

Tags: docker, jena, fuseki, triplestore

I'm following the instructions for [this Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/stain/jena-fuseki/), which describes how to set up a new containerized RDF triplestore using Apache Fuseki. I think I can automate all the steps in those instructions for my data set using a Dockerfile, but there's one step, under "recognizing the dataset in Fuseki," that has you enter the GUI interface and add a new dataset there. Since I'd eventually like to automate this process, I'd like to find a command-line way to add a new dataset. It doesn't need to be anything fancy, just add a new dataset with a given name, like "db." Is there a way to do that? (And also, I guess, a way to run that command in the docker container?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

(1) Start your container with `docker run -p 3030:3030 -it stain/jena-fuseki`.

(2) Find your container's id $$$ with `docker ps`.

(3) Copy a `config.ttl` file to your docker container with `docker container cp config.ttl $$$:config.ttl`. An example `config.ttl` can look as follows:

```
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix :        <#> .

<#service1> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    fuseki:name                       "ds" ;       # http://host:port/ds
    fuseki:serviceQuery               "sparql" ;   # SPARQL query service
    fuseki:serviceQuery               "query" ;    # SPARQL query service (alt name)
    fuseki:serviceUpdate              "update" ;   # SPARQL update service
    fuseki:serviceUpload              "upload" ;   # Non-SPARQL upload service
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;     # SPARQL Graph store protocol (read and write)
    # A separate read-only graph store endpoint:
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore      "get" ;      # SPARQL Graph store protocol (read only)
    fuseki:dataset                   <#dataset> ;
    .

<#dataset> rdf:type      tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "DB" ;
    # Query timeout on this dataset (1s, 1000 milliseconds)
    ja:context [ ja:cxtName "arq:queryTimeout" ;  ja:cxtValue "1000" ] ;
    # Make the default graph be the union of all named graphs.
    ## tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ;
     .
```

(4) Commit the changes to your container with `docker container commit $$$ stackoverflow/jena-fuseki:latest`.

(5) Restart your container with: `docker run -p 3030:3030 -it stackoverflow/jena-fuseki ./fuseki-server --config=/config.ttl`.

(6) If you now go to `http://localhost:3030` you should see your dataset.